# Can we use Google Test Account Billing settings APIs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-ads-api, google-ad-manager

I'd like to set billing information for a **Test Account**, but I can't set it using the Google Ads library or even the Google Ads UI.

The message error is:

```
Your account's access level doesn't include billing information. If you need access to billing, speak with your account admin.
```

I tried to search about it and found [this google groups conversation](https://groups.google.com/g/adwords-api/c/fqjK3G0bFlQ), but I couldn't find what I'm looking for.

Any idea how to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Production accounts serve ads that are rendered to users and billing is involved. Test accounts, on the other hand, appear in the Google Ads UI as cancelled accounts since there is no active billing or serving, though API requests still work. The test account does omit the billing information. However, you still can create the test client account under the test manager account. All the test client accounts are invisible by default.

To view test accounts in the UI, you can [unhide the accounts](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7519830) by choosing to view cancelled accounts. You can refer to this [code example](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/samples/create-customer) and create the test client account via the API.

Refer to the [link](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/first-call/overview#test_account) for more information on Google Ads API.

Comment: I appreciate your help so much, you meant that's I can't use the Billing APIs with the test accounts?

Comment: Yes, There is no active billing for test accounts, though API requests still work.